# Order of fields in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

Recently I made a PR to a repo to add a `typings` field in `package.json`, and the maintainer proposed the following change:

```
-   "typings": "./src/index.d.ts",
-   "main": "./src/index.js",
-   "exports": "./src/index.js",
+   "main": "./src/index.js",
+   "exports": "./src/index.js",
+   "types": "./src/index.d.ts",
```

I wonder if there is a recommended rule or convention of orders of entries in `package.json`.

Comment: well, he changed "typings" to "types" for a start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the maintainer has a formating tool enabled like prettier that automatically sorts the package.json file. Or maybe they just like ordering their scripts in order of execution. Either way it's a json object so ultimately the order of the fields does not matter, just the nesting.

Another thought is they could be using a special batch or shell script that hand cranks the package.json during CD, converting the scripts object to an array that gets run in order of execution. Without seeing the github I can't be sure though.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier-package-json